# Push UIViewController from Settings

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I'm trying to push a `UIViewController`from a Settings bundle, like this:

[image: Twitter Example 1][1]
[image: Twitter Example 2][2]

I have the Child Pane pointing to another plist but I don't see anything in the documentation how to tie a `UIViewController` to the selector. Is there a PSSpecifier I am missing or is this just Private API functionality (hence why Twitter/Facebook/Flickr etc. have it but many others don't?

Also, I'm using InAppSettingsKit for the time being but is there a more current solution that simplifies the Settings bundle/In App Settings synchronization?

I'm pretty frustrated with Apple's poor documentation regarding Settings and how to integrate (somewhat) commonly used functionality into other applications.

Comment: I believe you cannot present a custom viewController. ChildPanes should be built just like any other settings bundle configuration. The facebook/twitter tie in is actually done by apple itself i presume.

Comment: @Erakk this is my suspicion after a few hours of searching. If that really is the case, it's regrettable since the functionality could be nice to have.

Comment: Yes, Apple is quite close minded regarding that, but that had changed recently (now you can have some custom controls in the Control Center, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the standard Apple settings scheme. InAppSettingsKit does allow it. Check the paragraph on [custom view controllers](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#custom-viewcontrollers) to push your own view controller.

Alternatively, you can also use a [custom button](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#iaskbuttonspecifier) to manually present a modal view controller.